# Time format used in .ics file?

Tags: java, events, calendar, icalendar

I am creating an .ics file in Java, and I need to know what date and time format to use.

Here is the current format of my ics file:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120901T180000
DTEND:20120901T183000
SUMMARY:my birthday
LOCATION:Bangalore
DESCRIPTION:Every one is welcome..!! time to party
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I used `ISO_DATETIME_TIME_ZONE_FORMAT` to convert my date to the required format, but it returned `2012-09-01T18:00:00+00:00`

What is the date format used in the `DTSTART` and `DTEND` values? Specifically, how can I format this properly in Java?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With Java you could use

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
```

See more at [iCalendar RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)

Comment: If that .ics file is sent to me in London in January (GMT +0) or August (GMT +1) or to Someone in east Europe (GMT +3) do we start the meeting at the same time ?
Is that supposed to be UTC time so everyone will get the correct local time? 
I'm creating .ics file and I'm trying to add the TZId (time zone Id, like "Europe/London") and try to figure out how that change the time (should I consider the time offeset?).

Comment: Looking at the RFC above, 3.3.5 there are description of sending times without timezones, in UTC, or specific TZID. Ex: 19970714T133000 (local for everyone), 19970714T173000Z (UTC) and TZID=America/New_York:19970714T133000 (New York). https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any reservations using a third-party library that will make this easier? If not, take a look at [ICal4j](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Thank you, but i had a look at that, and it seemed much simpler to just write the ics file onto an outputsteam and download it. also im trying to avoid using a third-party library, i just need to know which format the date and time should be parsed in.

Comment: A [little googling](http://bit.ly/IXOrlM) will get you the answer; [one the results](https://drupal.org/node/747490) says `The iCal Date format is in the form of yyyymmddThhmmss`; @roger-lindsjo's note above has the pattern you can use with `SimpleDateFormat` to parse it

Answer (score 0):

Building off of Roger's answer, I wrote a quick block of code for anyone who wants a quick online "converter".

https://repl.it/repls/SomeNovelFields

The code to get something compiling and running is here:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");

        try {
        Date date = dateFormat.parse("20140110T000732");
                System.out.println(date);

        } catch(Exception e) {

        }
     }
}
```